# How can I update with a NULL value

Tags: php

I am trying to update a mysql table. If there is no value I want null but I'm getting 0 if $ODate is empty. Actually I'm getting 0000-00-00. What I need to do is get rid of the ' ' then it will take the NULL value but then it doesn't work if there is a valid date value.

```
if (($_POST['OrderDate'])==null){$ODate='NULL';}else {$ODate=$_POST['OrderDate'];}
```

//this will update a valid date but returns 0000-00-00 if set to NULL

```
"UPDATE tblLoads SET OrderDate = '$ODate',
```

//this will update NULL but returns 0000-00-00 if a valid date

```
"UPDATE tblLoads SET OrderDate = $ODate,
```

Comment: Have you considered using prepared statements/pdo/mysqli?

Comment: I may have to learn about them I have NO experiance with them at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ODate = empty($_POST['OrderDate']) ? "NULL" : "'$_POST[OrderDate]'";

$query = "UPDATE tblLoads SET OrderDate = $ODate, ...";
```

Comment: This gives 0000-00-00 if the date field is empty/blank.

Comment: I wrote my answer before you edited your question to show how `$ODate` was being set, I thought you wanted to work with `null`. I've updated it to show how to do it with `$_POST` data.

Comment: Thanks Barmar that did the trick. I should have been clearer where the date was coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an if else, checking for if `$ODate` is NULL, if it is then don't use the quotes, if it isn't null, then use the quotes.

e.g.,

```
if (!is_null($ODate)) {
  $ODate = "'" . $ODate . "'";
}

"UPDATE tblLoads SET OrderDate = $ODate,
```

Comment: It will allow null and the default is null. By removeing the ' ' around $ODate I can update to a null but then a real date dosen't work.

Comment: which is why I'm suggesting that if there IS a date in the $ODate value, wrap it in quotes, otherwise leave the quotes off. Edited to show example.

Comment: This returns 0000-00-00 if the date field is empty.